# Responsive content wrap when using position absolute footer

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Working on a new design using bootstrap3 and trying to stretch the page so that even if there's not enough content to fill the page, the footer section would stay to the bottom.

The reason why I'm using position absolute, is because there's a link from the billing software that's being added within the content, I don't want to remove the link but position it a bit to the bottom in the footer section, in the center bottom, thus since I can't control where this will appear(do know where appears, just can't control), using position absolute on the specific element helps me here.

Now, that's not issue, just saying why I need to use position absolute and why I made the divs like this:

```
wrapper
   >>wrapper_content
   >>wrapper_footer
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/raicabogdan/jsk1b7ua/4/

the footer section is properly set to the bottom, however for some reason, the wrapper_content does not go 100% height automatically on load or on window resize. Also if you resize to mobile view, content will go down few table rows.

The content goes under the footer section.

What am I doing wrong here? Left a fiddle of the html page along with some css that I felt were needed above.

Hope there's someone that could get me out of this.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this link. I have used this method to get the footer to stay at the bottom of the window.

http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

Comment: Not for this case, that's what I used before, but then I can't position the link I mentioned since you need position relative to a parent object to use absolute. Haven't tried yet using this method and setting position relative to the body, would that work?

Comment: Ok so I think I get it now.  
.wrapper_content {
min-height: 100%;
 padding-bottom: 235px; <-------- You still need this
}

and that padding should be set to the height of the footer.  when you go to mobile responsive view you may need to set a height for the footer and re-declared the padding for .wrapper_content in a media query.

Comment: I guess that could do for a little hack and get rid of the issue. Waiting to see if anyone has any other ideas.

Comment: ok good luck, but I think that is the only way it will work with your current markup.